# What is the equivalent of "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, upsert

In MySQL, I can insert rows and update them if primary key is duplicate with following syntax (I used pymsql):

```
INSERT INTO activities(scenario_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date \
              ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) \
               ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \
               end_date = %s, \
               start_date = %s
```

But in PostgreSQL, it wants me to use `ON CONFLICT (primary_key) DO UPDATE SET`

It means I have to explicitly write the `primary_key` name. But MySQL automatically took care of it with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` , you see the magical `KEY` word?

Is there a way to do the similar thing, something like `ON CONFLICT KEY DO UPDATE SET`?

Comment: The reason why you don't have to specify a constraint in MySQL is, that it can't handle anything but the primary key. In Postgres you have the possibility to specify which kind of conflict you want to avoid.

Comment: Offtopic: When you have a start_date and an end_date, the datatype "daterange" might be a better choice: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html